# JAVASCRIPT BACKEND DESKTOP

Tags: javascript

Duvida sobre javascript, ele da para usar como backend para desenvolvimento de aplicação?

Da para fazer aplicativos mobile com banco de dados?

Usam bastante nodejs para desenvolvimento web, com ele da para usar com banco de dados? a source do codigo o usuário ve quando inspecionar o elemento?

Tenho uma duvida simples mas que me impede de ir atrás, me recomendaram javascript para começar vejo que da para fazer muitos coisas com ele.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode desenvolver backend com javascript utilizando a tecnologia [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/).

Com o Node você pode conectar a diversos bancos de dados como MySQL, MongoDB, Redis, PostgreSQL, etc.

Dá uma olhada cuidadosa no NodeJS + express. O express é um módulo do NodeJS para implementar serviços web, como você faria com o APACHE+PHP.

Para Node tem muitos e muitos módulos que você pode usar através do npm, que é o repositório de libs.

[Neste link](http://nodebr.com/primeiros-passos-com-express-em-node-js/) tem um guia excelente para começar.

Boa sorte nos estudos!

Comment: Muito obrigado, ja tinha dado uma olhada nesse artigo unica duvida que me resta os dados de acesso a banco e outras coisa que não deve ser exibida no front end como geralmente o javascript é, com node fica tudo no backend ?

Comment: Sim, o NodeJS é o javascript que roda no backend (no servidor). Na prática, os desenvolvedores pegaram a máquina javascript do chrome e transformaram ela em uma potente engine de js para o servidor.

Comment: Complementando, o node roda no servidor, assim como o PHP.